# Не проходит тест kibana webhook telegram?

Tags: telegram, kibana

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][[image: URL][1[][1]]Простой вопрос,но не могу решить: не проходит тест из Edit connector в кибане в telegram. В kibana.log ругается : telegram: error calling webhook, invalid response: [400] Bad Request","
URL вроде правильный (скрин)
Вот полный лог : {"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.0"},"@timestamp":"2023-07-15T14:24:46.127+00:00","message":"action execution failure: .webhook:3f168540-22f0-11ee-9e0e-67c22f519ced: telegram: error calling webhook, invalid response: [400] Bad Request","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.actions.webhook"},"process":{"pid":771},"span":{"id":"4103be3c82023835"},"trace":{"id":"2e87d4468f35c5a711b0faf9faa5f29e"}}введите сюда описание изображения

Comment: из терминала curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot123456782:AAGfbWzqNJDlS0wiqao2DUeX7Cb7zJfXtgo/sendMessage \
 -F chat_id=1234567890' -F text='test message'  тест приходит в телегу. А из kibana Edit connector ошибка 400

Comment: Решено: Content-Type     Application/json
 
 {
     "text": "text"
  }

Comment: Но alert из kibana в telegram не приходит,хотя тот же alert на почту ок